# Rdrobust installation does not work in Stata 13

Tags: stata

I tried to install RDrobust with the following command:

```
net install rdrobust, from(https://sites.google.com/site/rdpackages/rdrobust/stata) replace
```

I am given an error which recommends checking another website but the instructions are unclear. I know that it properly installs in Stata 14 but I only have access to Stata 13. Would one of the following solutions work to use the rdrobust package in Stata 13?

(1) Manually install the packages in Stata 13 from the files [here](https://sites.google.com/site/rdpackages/rdrobust/stata)?

(2) I read that this package had a major upgrade in 2016. Maybe it it possible to find the old link to upload the old package? Does someone know this?

I am using this for a class where the students only have access to a Stata 13 license.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Stata 15.1 the following is shown by `search rdrobust`

```
Search of official help files, FAQs, Examples, SJs, and STBs

SJ-17-2 st0366_1  . .  rdrobust: Software for regression-discontinuity designs
        . . . . .  S. Calonico, M. D. Cattaneo, M. H. Farrell, and R. Titiunik
        (help rdrobust, rdbwselect, rdplot if installed)
        Q2/17   SJ 17(2):372--404
        describes a major upgrade to the Stata (and R) rdrobust package,
        which provides a wide array of estimation, inference, and
        falsification methods for the analysis and interpretation of
        regression-discontinuity designs

SJ-14-4 st0366  . .  Robust data-driven inference in reg.-discontinuity design
        . . . . . . . . . . . . . S. Calonico, M. D. Cattaneo, and R. Titiunik
        (help rdrobust, rdbwselect, rdplot if installed)
        Q4/14   SJ 14(4):909--946
        conducts robust data-driven statistical inference in
        regression-discontinuity designs
```

That's how to find the files. In Stata 13, you may need

```
search rdrobust, all
```

Then follow the latest link `st0366_1` to install.

Trying to install from elsewhere is all too likely to lead to partial installs and/or installs in the wrong places, unless a user has a sound understanding of packages and `adopath`.

I have not checked on whether `rdrobust` will run in Stata 13.

Answer (score 1):

rdrobust works on Stata 13.1 or higher, due to some new functions they added in Mata.